# PHP isset get issue error in else statement

Tags: php, isset

I am trying to get it so index.php?steamusr=username get's set as the var and if none is specified it just displays a the error specified in the else statement.

I have tried if empty and isset. I have been trying every combo I can find and still nothing. This is my current code, the bottom is the error message. Thanks!

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['steamusr'])) {
    $user = $_GET['steamusr'];
    $myinv = 'http://steamcommunity.com/id/$user/inventory/json/295110/1/';
    $content2 = file_get_contents($myinv);
    $json2 = json_decode($content2, true);
    $imgurlbase = 'http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/';

    foreach($json2['rgDescriptions'] as $i){
       $item = $i['market_name'];
       $icon = $i['icon_url'];
       $fetchdata = 'http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=295110&currency=1&market_hash_name=' . urlencode($item);
       $grab = file_get_contents($fetchdata);
       $id = json_decode($grab, true);
       echo '<img src="'. $imgurlbase . $icon . '/64fx64f">' . '<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">'.'<span class="badge">1</span> ' . $item .'</a>' . '<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">'.'Low</br>'. $id['lowest_price'].'</a>'.'<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">'.'Avg</br>'. $id['median_price'].'</a>'.'<br>';
     }
else {
    echo '<h1>No steam user set</h2>';
}
}
?>
```

Here is the error:

> [Wed Aug 19 09:24:33.723604 2015] [:error] [pid 21378] [client 67.90.138.68:62702] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in /var/www/index.php on line 58

Comment: can `else` be use with `foreach` ?

Comment: a missing `if` condition for the `else` or place it (else) outside your last line, being for the `if (isset($_GET['steamusr'])) {` condition.

Comment: actually yeah... it's misplaced. Place `else {
    echo '<h1>No steam user set</h2>';
      }` after your last brace. That goes for `if (isset($_GET['steamusr'])) {`

Comment: Indent your code sensibly and these sort of errors are Plain to see.

Comment: Answer(s) posted below and comments above, but no response from the OP. If what has been posted below did not solve this, then your GET array `$_GET['steamusr']` may be failing you. If you're not already setup for error reporting.... Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. Your code's execution relies on that conditional statement. Echo/var_dump the array/variable(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `else` part works with your first conditional statement, therefore it needs to be placed after your last brace.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['steamusr'])) {
    $user = $_GET['steamusr'];
    $myinv = 'http://steamcommunity.com/id/$user/inventory/json/295110/1/';
    $content2 = file_get_contents($myinv);
    $json2 = json_decode($content2, true);
    $imgurlbase = 'http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/';

    foreach($json2['rgDescriptions'] as $i){
        $item = $i['market_name'];
        $icon = $i['icon_url'];
        $fetchdata = 'http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=295110&currency=1&market_hash_name=' . urlencode($item);
        $grab = file_get_contents($fetchdata);
        $id = json_decode($grab, true);
        echo '<img src="'. $imgurlbase . $icon . '/64fx64f">' . '<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">'.'<span class="badge">1</span> ' . $item .'</a>' . '<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">'.'Low</br>'. $id['lowest_price'].'</a>'.'<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">'.'Avg</br>'. $id['median_price'].'</a>'.'<br>';
     }

  // else was here before

} else {
    echo '<h1>No steam user set</h2>';
}

?>
```

Comment: [That](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32097031/php-isset-get-issue-error-in-else-statement#comment52088839_32097031) goes for you too Ralph. hhehe

Comment: @RiggsFolly Indeed... unless you're up to doing a bit of magic there Smokey ;-)

Comment: My peasure, I live to server

Comment: @RiggsFolly *Thanks Smokey*

Comment: Thanks man that fixed it, appreciate all the feedback!

Comment: @alexj You're very much welcome Alex, *cheers*

Answer (score 1):

Change this part of code:

```
foreach($json2['rgDescriptions'] as $i){
$item = $i['market_name'];
$icon = $i['icon_url'];
$fetchdata = 'http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=295110&currency=1&market_hash_name=' . urlencode($item);
$grab = file_get_contents($fetchdata);
$id = json_decode($grab, true);
echo '<img src="'. $imgurlbase . $icon . '/64fx64f">' . '<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">'.'<span class="badge">1</span> ' . $item .'</a>' . '<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">'.'Low</br>'. $id['lowest_price'].'</a>'.'<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">'.'Avg</br>'. $id['median_price'].'</a>'.'<br>';
  }
  else {
echo '<h1>No steam user set</h2>';
  }
}
```

to

```
foreach($json2['rgDescriptions'] as $i){
    $item = $i['market_name'];
    $icon = $i['icon_url'];
    $fetchdata = 'http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=295110&currency=1&market_hash_name=' . urlencode($item);
    $grab = file_get_contents($fetchdata);
    $id = json_decode($grab, true);
    echo '<img src="'. $imgurlbase . $icon . '/64fx64f">' . '<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">'.'<span class="badge">1</span> ' . $item .'</a>' . '<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">'.'Low</br>'. $id['lowest_price'].'</a>'.'<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">'.'Avg</br>'. $id['median_price'].'</a>'.'<br>';
  }
}
else {
    echo '<h1>No steam user set</h2>';
  }
```

Now you were putting your else after the foreach, instead of the if.